# A Simple, data binding doesn't seem to work, I'm wondering what on earth I've done wrong

Tags: angularjs

EDIT: i arranged the files so the JS file is the last one.. but its still not working

The result when I open this up in firefox is simply {{message}}
I've named the files:  html.html  and js.js

**HTML file**

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js.js", type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="abc">
    {{message}}
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript file**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

abc.controller('abc', function($scope){

$scope.message = 'booya';
});
```

Comment: Based on the code you shared; I don't understand why anything would show up; as you haven't shared any code which will display the message variable.  Although, you do have you script tags in the wrong order.  The Angular.module can't be created until the angular framework is "imported/initialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller should be defined as:

```
app.controller('abc', function($scope){

$scope.message = 'booya';
});
```

You have mentioned abc.controller. It seems where the issue is

Answer (score 1):

You need to load js.js after angularjs, which means that your  should look like:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js">    </script>
<script src="js.js", type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have a `body` or a `ngController`. And you should change the order of your js files, as follows:

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js.js", type='text/javascript'></script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="abc">
    {{message}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was about to post this; but you beat me too it.  I believe the original question is lacking in code; because I don't understand why--bsaed on the code shared {{Mmessage}} would be shown to the screen.